# How do you create an array from a delimited string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of categories stored as a semicolon string in db.

I have a kendo select tag that I need to populate with these values.

The select tag needs the values as an array in the form:

```
[{catText: "first category", catValue: "first category"},{catText: "second category", catValue: "second category"}...]
```

Note: both text and value contain the same string.

My JavaScript/jQuery is:

```
//define my category dataobject
    function Cat(catValue,catText) {
        this.catValue= catValue;
        this.catText= catText;
    }

    // set value for msCategories
    var vData = [];
    var cats= '@Model.Categories';
    alert(cats); //this returns "Alcohol; Vodka"
    var cData = cats.split(";");
    $.each(cData, function (index, value) {
        var obj = new Cat(value, value);
        vData.push(obj);
    });

alert(vData); //this gives me [{object Object},{object Object}]
```

How do I get an array where it will be `[{catText: "Alcohol", catValue: "Alcohol"},{catText: "Vodka", catValue: "Vodka"}]`

Comment: What happens if you replace `alert` with `console.log` what do you see in the console?

Comment: It looks like your code already gives you the array your require: an array of objects, with each object containing a catText and a catValue. The problem is in the alert statement: it does not output your array as you expect (as others point out in answers). However, the array itself does contain the correct contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run alert() on an array of objects, it will return the type of the item, rather than a stringified value.

If you use `console.log( vData )` you'll more than likely see the data in the structure you'd expect.

Other things you could try would be

`alert( vData[0], vData[1], vData[2] );` if you just need to debug something

or even

`alert( JSON.stringify( vData ) );`

So you most likely do not have an issue, just the way you're trying to view the information is not really suitable.

Comment: Ok... using alert(JSON.stringify( vData )); I get [{"catText": "Alcohol", "catValue": "Alcohol"},{"catText": "Vodka", "catValue": "Vodka"}] i.e. I'm getting quotes around catText and catValue.

Comment: using JSON.stringify will make it into a string, that can be converted back into JSON if needed, so when its been passed through JSON.stringify it will add quotes around them. try using just console.log(vData) if that gives you the structure you expect, then your all good!

Answer (score 1):

So you want JSON (Javascript Object Notation), you can do it with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
var vData = [{catText: "first category", catValue: "first category"},{catText: "second category", catValue: "second category"}]

document.write(JSON.stringify(vData));
```

Then you can see that your Array contains what you expected, `alert` only try to call [`object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) on each item so it return `[object Object]`